# Sort vectors and lists using a template version of quicksort

Tags: c++, list, templates, vector, quicksort

I need to make a template version of quicksort that sorts both vectors and lists. Currently, my code is only able to sort lists successfully. The output shows that the vector elements have moved around but remain unsorted.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using std::vector;
using std::list;
using std::iterator;


template<typename T>
T partition(T begin, T end) {
    if(begin==end){
        return end;
    }
    T pivot= begin;
    T split= begin;
    for(T I= ++begin; I != end; ++I){
        if(*I <= *pivot){
            std::advance(split,1);
            std::swap(*I,*split);
        }
    }
    std::swap(*split,*pivot);
    return split;
}
template<typename T>
void quicksort(T begin, T end) {
    if (2> std::distance(begin,end)){
        return;
    }
    T middle= partition(begin,end);
    std::advance(middle,1);
    quicksort(middle,end);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    list<int> mylist= {23,14,31,57,28,49};
    vector<int> myvector= {5,1,4,2,8,18,3,33};

    quicksort(myvector.begin(),myvector.end());
    std::cout<<"The sorted vector:";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    for(auto x:myvector){
        std::cout<<x<<" ";
    }

    std::cout<<std::endl;

    quicksort(mylist.begin(),mylist.end());
    std::cout<<"The sorted list:";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    for(auto x:mylist){
        std::cout<<x<<" ";
    }   
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code above is:

The sorted vector:
3 1 4 2 5 8 18 33
The sorted list:
14 23 28 31 49 57

As you can see, the vector is not sorted correctly. I want to thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Why quicksort and no std::sort ?

Comment: @DieterLücking This code is part of an assignment I had to complete. The assignment made it mandatory to convert quicksort into a template version of quicksort.

Comment: @vsoftco This code is part of an assignment for one of my class. I completely agree with you, but the assignment directions explicitly stated that I had to sort a list and a vector to show that my template version of quicksort could sort both cases.

Comment: it's not working properly even for lists. replace `vector myvector` with `list myvector` in the vector definition in `main`, and it's still not sorting properly. Test first your `partition` function with a debugger. quicksort should then be trivial.

Comment: @vsoftco You are right. I didn't see that. I am going to look into that now.